# Incorrect year shows up when using GetLastWriteTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line of code:

```
<%= System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  %>
```

In Explorer, the file shows up as being modified on 1/2/2012.  However this code outputs 1600-01-02.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing that is because:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.
>
> [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)

Once that is adjusted to your timezone; that is why you are getting `1600-01-02`.

I don't believe `GetLastWriteTime` understands a virtual path. It is expecting a physical path. Try:

```
<%= System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>
```

You can use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to map a virtual path to a physical path.

Comment: Good catch. The coincidence that the default date of the file and the actual date let me to assume it was actually finding the file but returning the wrong date!